# Dotted strings to properties

Tags: groovy, gradle

I've got a hash of strings similar to this:

```
Map map = ['a.b.c': 'Hi']
```

... that I need to use in gradle to expand an expression like this:

```
This is a greeting: ${a.b.c}
```

If I use the gradle copy task with expand I will get an error message 'No such property: a'.

Is there any way to get gradle/groovy to convert that map into the properties I need to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what your needs are, but if you just need to replace property-like tokens and don't need the full power of Groovy templates, the `filter()` method in combination with Ant's `ReplaceTokens` class is a safer (and faster) bet than `expand()`. See [Filtering files](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:filtering_files) in the Gradle User Guide.

Comment: Filter doesn't accept multichar tokens. However, in the end the troubles of getting the expand working, outweighed the troubles of changing all tokens.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a built-in answer, but it here is a complete, self-contained method that can be used as a meta method on Map to do what you want:

```
Map map = ['a.b.c': 'Hi', 'a.b.d': 'Yo', 'f.g.h': 'Howdy']

Map.metaClass.expandKeys = { separator = '.' ->
    def mergeMaps = { a, b ->
        b.each{ k, v ->
            if(a[k] && (v instanceof Map)) {
                mergeMaps(a[k], v)
            } else {
                a[k] = v
            }
        }
        a
    }
    delegate.inject([:]){ result, k, v ->
        mergeMaps(result, k.tokenize(separator).reverse().inject(v){last, subkey -> [(subkey):last] })
    }
}

assert map.expandKeys() == [a:[b:[c:"Hi", d:"Yo"]], f:[g:[h:"Howdy"]]]
```

It also allows for different separators than `.`, just pass the separator into the `expandKeys` method

If you want to use it like a normal function, then you can do this instead:

```
Map map = ['a.b.c': 'Hi', 'a.b.d': 'Yo', 'f.g.h': 'Howdy']

def expandKeys = { Map input, separator = '.' ->
    def mergeMaps = { a, b ->
        b.each{ k, v ->
            if(a[k] && (v instanceof Map)) {
                mergeMaps(a[k], v)
            } else {
                a[k] = v
            }
        }
        a
    }
    input.inject([:]){ result, k, v ->
        mergeMaps(result, k.tokenize(separator).reverse().inject(v){last, subkey -> [(subkey):last] })
    }
}

assert expandKeys(map) == [a:[b:[c:"Hi", d:"Yo"]], f:[g:[h:"Howdy"]]]
```

The main trick, besides merging the maps, is to split then reverse each key.  Then the final hierarchy can be built up backwards.  Also, there may be a better way to handle the merge, because I don't like the hanging `a` at the end.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this example may not work the way you'd expect if your original map contains sub-maps as values.  (They will be merged in instead of left as-is.)  The solution to this is a more complicated function that merges as it tokenizes the string.  Even then, you *might* have some issues with sub-maps.

Comment: I had some trouble running that within gradle or groovysh. I got the error 'groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException'. I settled on not doing this at all because of the complications (i.e. you can't have both a and a.b).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Gradle but maybe this will help....

If you have a Map

```
Map map = ['a.b.c': 'Hi']
```

Then you can't retrieve the value 'Hi' using

```
map.a.b.c
```

Instead, you must use:

```
map.'a.b.c'
```

or

```
map['a.b.c']
```

Comment: Yes; that's my original problem. However, I thought that must be a common problem, with a solution; may be in form of a builder.